# Share a queue between main process and a Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a server that at a request from a client needs to launch a thread to handle some updates from another server.

The idea is that the thread then needs to watch for some events. When an event come then It should push the event on a Queue.
Meanwhile the main process should check if there are events on the queue. If there are it should print it.

The code I am using is this one:

```
def Post(self, request_iterator, context):
        print("Post")
        for request in request_iterator:
            global event_queue
            event_queue = queue.Queue()
            if hasattr(request , "Thing")==False:
                print("No Thing")
                print(request)
            for obj in request.objects:
                for idobj in obj.idObject:
                    print(obj)
                    threads = []
                    for prop in obj.properties:
                        process = collector.subscribe_to_events(int(idobj) , None , prop.name, None )
                        process.start()
                        print(idobj , prop.name)
                        threads.append(process)
                        while not event_queue.empty():
                            print("EVENT")
                            event = event_queue.get(True)
                            print(event)
        print("Finish")
```

After some check the thread is called in the following way:

```
Thread(target=handler_subscriptions , args= (path1 , address, endpoint , ))


def handler_subscriptions( path1 , address , endpoint ) :
   print("--------------------------------")
   client = SSEClient(path1)
   for event in client:
       if "ep" in event.data:
           #print(endpoint)
           #print(event.data)
           var = json.loads(event.data)
           #print(var)
           if var["ep"]==endpoint:
               #print(var["val"]["id"],var["val"]["value"])
               data=dict()
               print("newdata")
               data["id"]=str(var["val"]["id"])
               data["value"]=str(var["val"]["value"])
               event_queue.put(data)
               print(list(event_queue.queue))
           global number_observe
       if number_observe==0:
           print("Closing...")
           client.resp.close()
           break
```

What I want is that the events should be consumed too by the main thread.
What I get is that the events are only pushed in the queue.
Any idea for solving it?

Comment: You are constantly creating new `Queue`s.  If you ever find that the current `Queue` is empty (perhaps because the thread hasn't even finished starting up yet), you abandon it - anything the thread pushes to it later is lost.

Comment: Do you mean because global event_queue is in a loop? That´s because to different request there should be different queue. The request I am sending is just one, so there won´t be different queue. Later of course I need to handle better the scalability of my service

Comment: Ok, perhaps you do need multiple queues - but you'd then need to keep *all* of them around for as long as the associated thread is still alive.  Having the queue momentarily become empty doesn't indicate that the thread is done.

Comment: Ok, I used a while True loop with a locking-get. Thanks for your point ;)